# In C# how to avoid array loop to be carry forwaded using timer_tick

Tags: c#

I have a small application which reads 17 meter via mod-bus open-source industrial networks library. 
In C# I am using to Read the Holding Registers from 17 meters simultaneously via Serial Port as seen in the code.

But in some instances to read the holding register the write command to the serial port is given and there is no reply from that command and the script continues to the next holding register to read. But the skipped register value retrieved is nothing, but still the array read from the previous command value.
I have tried to mark the array to null still when the port is not read the previous command for read holding is carry forwarded and in this case i.e.
Meter 1 is read and Meter 2 is not read the Value of Meter1 is shown in Meter 2 textbox and stream file.

How can I avoid the carry forwarding in this case in a timer loop.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using IndustrialNetwork.Modbus.RTU;
using IndustrialNetwork.Modbus.ASCII;
using IndustrialNetwork.Modbus.TCP;
using IndustrialNetwork.Modbus.DataType;
using IndustrialNetwork.Modbus.Comm;
using System.IO.Ports;
using System.IO;

namespace ModbusTCP_Example
{
public partial class SecureMeterReaderMPPGCL : Form
{
    private IModbusMaster modbusMaster = null;
    private SerialPort serialPort = null;
    private const int DELAYS = 500;// delay 100 ms

    public SecureMeterReaderMPPGCL()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        aboutToolStripMenuItem.Click += new EventHandler(aboutToolStripMenuItem_Click);
    }

    private void SecureMeterReaderMPPGCL_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            // Mode: MODBUS RTU
            serialPort = new SerialPort();
            serialPort.ReadBufferSize = 4096;
            serialPort.WriteBufferSize = 4096;
            serialPort.BaudRate = 9600;
            serialPort.Parity = Parity.None;
            serialPort.StopBits = StopBits.One;
            serialPort.DataBits = 8;
            serialPort.Handshake = Handshake.None;
            serialPort.RtsEnable = true;
            serialPort.DtrEnable = true;
            //serialPort.ReadTimeout = 0;
            serialPort.PortName = "COM3";
            //serialPort.WriteTimeout = 0;
            //serialPort = new SerialPort("COM3", 9600, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);
            ModbusSerialPortAdapter serialAdapter = new ModbusSerialPortAdapter(serialPort);
            modbusMaster = new ModbusRTUMaster();
            modbusMaster.sModbusSerialPortAdapter(serialAdapter);

            //// Mode: MODBUS ASCII
            //serialPort = new SerialPort("COM3", 9600, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);
            //ModbusSerialPortAdapter serialAdapter = new ModbusSerialPortAdapter(serialPort);
            //master = new ModbusASCIIMaster();
            //master.sModbusSerialPortAdapter(serialAdapter);

            //// Mode: MODBUS TCP/IP.
            //master = new ModbusTCPMaster("127.0.0.1", 502);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(this, ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }

    private void btnConnect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            modbusMaster.Connection(); // Connect to Modbus Slave.
            btnConnect.Enabled = false;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(this, ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }

    private void btnDisconnect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            modbusMaster.Disconnection(); // Connect to Modbus Slave.
            btnConnect.Enabled = true;
            timerPoll.Stop();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(this, ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }

    private void btnReadHoldingRegisters_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (!btnConnect.Enabled) timerPoll.Start();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(this, ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }

    private void timerPoll_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {

            ////Mode:Integer
            //ushort startAddress = 1;
            //byte[] temp = modbusMaster.ReadHoldingRegisters(1, string.Format("{0}", startAddress), 20);
            //short[] data = IndustrialNetwork.Modbus.DataType.Int.ToArray(temp);
            ////show.
            //Dictionary<ushort, short> result = new Dictionary<ushort, short>();
            //foreach (short value in data)
            //{
            //    result.Add(startAddress++, value);
            //}
            //dataGridView1.DataSource = result.ToArray();

            ////Mode:Float
            //ushort startAddress = 1;
            //byte[] temp = modbusMaster.ReadHoldingRegisters(1, string.Format("{0}", startAddress), 20);
            //float[] data = IndustrialNetwork.Modbus.DataType.Real.ToArrayInverse(temp);
            ////show.
            //Dictionary<ushort, float> result = new Dictionary<ushort, float>();
            //foreach (float value in data)
            //{
            //    result.Add(startAddress++, value);
            //}
            //dataGridView1.DataSource = result.ToArray();

            //Mode:Float
            ushort startAddress = 2122;
            byte[] temp = null;
            temp = modbusMaster.ReadHoldingRegisters(1, string.Format("{0}", startAddress), 2);
            if (temp != null && temp.Length > 0)
            {
                float[] data = IndustrialNetwork.Modbus.DataType.Real.ToArray(temp);
                //
                //Meter 1 File Write
                using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("FREQ.txt", true))
                {
                    float datar = float.Parse(string.Join(" ", data));
                    sw.WriteLine(datar);
                    textBox1.Text = datar.ToString();
                    Array.Clear(data, 0, data.Length);
                    Array.Clear(temp, 0, temp.Length);
                    //data = null;
                }
            }
            ////show.
            //Dictionary<ushort, float> result = new Dictionary<ushort, float>();
            //foreach (float value in data)
            //{
            //    result.Add(startAddress++, value);
            //    startAddress += 1;
            //    //Write
            //    //using (StreamWriter sw1 = new StreamWriter("MPPGCL.txt", true))
            //    //{
            //    //    sw1.WriteLine(value);
            //    //}

            //}
            //dataGridView1.DataSource = result.ToArray();
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(DELAYS);
            ////1 Register
            ushort startAddress1 = 2114;
            byte[] temp1 = null;
            temp1 = modbusMaster.ReadHoldingRegisters(1, string.Format("{0}", startAddress1), 2);
            if (temp1 != null && temp1.Length > 0)
            {
                float[] data1 = IndustrialNetwork.Modbus.DataType.Real.ToArray(temp1);
                //
                //Meter 1 File Write
                using (StreamWriter sw1 = new StreamWriter("MPPGCL_SGTPS_MTR1.txt", true))
                {
                    float datar1 = float.Parse(string.Join(" ", data1)) / 1000;
                    sw1.WriteLine(datar1);
                    textBox3.Text = datar1.ToString();
                    Array.Clear(data1, 0, data1.Length);
                    Array.Clear(temp1, 0, temp1.Length);
                    //data = null;
                }
            }
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(DELAYS);
            ////2 Register
            ushort startAddress2 = 2114;
            byte[] temp2 = null;
            temp2 = modbusMaster.ReadHoldingRegisters(2, string.Format("{0}", startAddress2), 2);
            if (temp2 != null && temp2.Length > 0)
            {
                float[] data2 = IndustrialNetwork.Modbus.DataType.Real.ToArray(temp2);
                //
                //Meter 2 File Write
                using (StreamWriter sw2 = new StreamWriter("MPPGCL_SGTPS_MTR2.txt", true))
                {
                    //var datar2 = int.Parse(string.Join(" ", data2))/1000;
                    //int myInt = int.Parse(datar2)/1000;
                    //int myInt2 = int.Parse(datar2);
                    float datar2 = float.Parse(string.Join(" ", data2)) / 1000;
                    sw2.WriteLine(datar2);
                    textBox4.Text = datar2.ToString();
                    Array.Clear(data2, 0, data2.Length);
                    Array.Clear(temp2, 0, temp2.Length);
                    //data2 = null;
                }
            }
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(DELAYS);
            ////3 Register
            ushort startAddress3 = 2114;
            byte[] temp3 = null;
            temp3 = modbusMaster.ReadHoldingRegisters(3, string.Format("{0}", startAddress3), 2);
            if (temp3 != null && temp3.Length > 0)
            {
                float[] data3 = IndustrialNetwork.Modbus.DataType.Real.ToArray(temp3);
                //
                //Meter 3 File Write
                using (StreamWriter sw3 = new StreamWriter("MPPGCL_SGTPS_MTR3.txt", true))
                {
                    float datar3 = float.Parse(string.Join(" ", data3)) / 1000;
                    sw3.WriteLine(datar3);
                    textBox6.Text = datar3.ToString();
                    Array.Clear(data3, 0, data3.Length);
                    Array.Clear(temp3, 0, temp3.Length);
                    //data3 = null;
                }
            }
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(DELAYS);
            ////4 Register
            ushort startAddress4 = 2114;
            byte[] temp4 = null;
            temp4 = modbusMaster.ReadHoldingRegisters(4, string.Format("{0}", startAddress4), 2);
            if (temp4 != null && temp4.Length > 0)
            {
                float[] data4 = IndustrialNetwork.Modbus.DataType.Real.ToArray(temp4);
                //
                //Meter 4 File Write
                using (StreamWriter sw4 = new StreamWriter("MPPGCL_SGTPS_MTR4.txt", true))
                {
                    float datar4 = float.Parse(string.Join(" ", data4)) / 1000;
                    sw4.WriteLine(datar4);
                    textBox5.Text = datar4.ToString();
                    Array.Clear(data4, 0, data4.Length);
                    Array.Clear(temp4, 0, temp4.Length);
                    //data4 = null;
                }
            }
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(DELAYS);
            ////5 Register
            ushort startAddress5 = 2114;
            byte[] temp5 = null;
            temp5 = modbusMaster.ReadHoldingRegisters(5, string.Format("{0}", startAddress5), 2);
            if (temp5 != null && temp5.Length > 0)
            {
                float[] data5 = IndustrialNetwork.Modbus.DataType.Real.ToArray(temp5);
                //
                //Meter 5 File Write
                using (StreamWriter sw5 = new StreamWriter("MPPGCL_SGTPS_MTR5.txt", true))
                {
                    float datar5 = float.Parse(string.Join(" ", data5)) / 1000;
                    sw5.WriteLine(datar5);
                    textBox8.Text = datar5.ToString();
                    Array.Clear(data5, 0, data5.Length);
                    Array.Clear(temp5, 0, temp5.Length);
                    //data5 = null;
                }
            }
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(DELAYS);
            ////6 Register
            ushort startAddress6 = 2114;
            byte[] temp6 = null;
            temp6 = modbusMaster.ReadHoldingRegisters(6, string.Format("{0}", startAddress6), 2);
            if (temp6 != null && temp6.Length > 0)
            {
                float[] data6 = IndustrialNetwork.Modbus.DataType.Real.ToArray(temp6);
                //
                //Meter 6 File Write
                using (StreamWriter sw6 = new StreamWriter("MPPGCL_SGTPS_MTR6.txt", true))
                {
                    float datar6 = float.Parse(string.Join(" ", data6)) / 1000;
                    sw6.WriteLine(datar6);
                    textBox7.Text = datar6.ToString();
                    Array.Clear(data6, 0, data6.Length);
                    Array.Clear(temp6, 0, temp6.Length);
                    //data6 = null;
                }
            }
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(DELAYS);
            ////7 Register
            ushort startAddress7 = 2114;
            byte[] temp7 = null;
            temp7 = modbusMaster.ReadHoldingRegisters(7, string.Format("{0}", startAddress7), 2);
            if (temp7 != null && temp7.Length > 0)
            {
                float[] data7 = IndustrialNetwork.Modbus.DataType.Real.ToArray(temp7);
                //
                //Meter 7 File Write
                using (StreamWriter sw7 = new StreamWriter("MPPGCL_SGTPS_MTR7.txt", true))
                {
                    float datar7 = float.Parse(string.Join(" ", data7)) / 1000;
                    sw7.WriteLine(datar7);
                    textBox14.Text = datar7.ToString();
                    Array.Clear(data7, 0, data7.Length);
                    Array.Clear(temp7, 0, temp7.Length);
                    //data7 = null;
                }
            }
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(DELAYS);
            ////8 Register
            ushort startAddress8 = 2114;
            byte[] temp8 = null;
            temp8 = modbusMaster.ReadHoldingRegisters(8, string.Format("{0}", startAddress8), 2);
            if (temp8 != null && temp8.Length > 0)
            {
                float[] data8 = IndustrialNetwork.Modbus.DataType.Real.ToArray(temp8);
                //
                //Meter 8 File Write
                using (StreamWriter sw8 = new StreamWriter("MPPGCL_SGTPS_MTR8.txt", true))
                {
                    float datar8 = float.Parse(string.Join(" ", data8)) / 1000;
                    sw8.WriteLine(datar8);
                    textBox13.Text = datar8.ToString();
                    Array.Clear(data8, 0, data8.Length);
                    Array.Clear(temp8, 0, temp8.Length);
                    //data8 = null;
                }
            }
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(DELAYS);
            ////9 Register
            ushort startAddress9 = 2114;
            byte[] temp9 = null;
            temp9 = modbusMaster.ReadHoldingRegisters(9, string.Format("{0}", startAddress9), 2);
            if (temp9 != null && temp9.Length > 0)
            {
                float[] data9 = IndustrialNetwork.Modbus.DataType.Real.ToArray(temp9);
                //
                //Meter 9 File Write
                using (StreamWriter sw9 = new StreamWriter("MPPGCL_SGTPS_MTR9.txt", true))
                {
                    float datar9 = float.Parse(string.Join(" ", data9)) / 1000;
                    sw9.WriteLine(datar9);
                    textBox12.Text = datar9.ToString();
                    Array.Clear(data9, 0, data9.Length);
                    Array.Clear(temp9, 0, temp9.Length);
                    //data9 = null;
                }
            }
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(DELAYS);
            ////10 Register
            ushort startAddress10 = 2114;
            byte[] temp10 = null;
            temp10 = modbusMaster.ReadHoldingRegisters(10, string.Format("{0}", startAddress10), 2);
            if (temp10 != null && temp10.Length > 0)
            {
                float[] data10 = IndustrialNetwork.Modbus.DataType.Real.ToArray(temp10);
                //
                //Meter 10 File Write
                using (StreamWriter sw10 = new StreamWriter("MPPGCL_SGTPS_MTR10.txt", true))
                {
                    float datar10 = float.Parse(string.Join(" ", data10)) / 1000;
                    sw10.WriteLine(datar10);
                    textBox11.Text = datar10.ToString();
                    Array.Clear(data10, 0, data10.Length);
                    Array.Clear(temp10, 0, temp10.Length);
                    //data10 = null;
                }
            }
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(DELAYS);
            ////11 Register
            ushort startAddress11 = 2114;
            byte[] temp11 = null;
            temp11 = modbusMaster.ReadHoldingRegisters(11, string.Format("{0}", startAddress11), 2);
            if (temp11 != null && temp11.Length > 0)
            {
                float[] data11 = IndustrialNetwork.Modbus.DataType.Real.ToArray(temp11);
                //
                //Meter 11 File Write
                using (StreamWriter sw11 = new StreamWriter("MPPGCL_SGTPS_MTR11.txt", true))
                {
                    float datar11 = float.Parse(string.Join(" ", data11)) / 1000;
                    sw11.WriteLine(datar11);
                    textBox10.Text = datar11.ToString();
                    Array.Clear(data11, 0, data11.Length);
                    Array.Clear(temp11, 0, temp11.Length);
                    //data11 = null;
                }
            }
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(DELAYS);
            ////12 Register
            ushort startAddress12 = 2114;
            byte[] temp12 = null;
            temp12 = modbusMaster.ReadHoldingRegisters(12, string.Format("{0}", startAddress12), 2);
            if (temp12 != null && temp12.Length > 0)
            {
                float[] data12 = IndustrialNetwork.Modbus.DataType.Real.ToArray(temp12);
                //
                //Meter 12 File Write
                using (StreamWriter sw12 = new StreamWriter("MPPGCL_SGTPS_MTR12.txt", true))
                {
                    float datar12 = float.Parse(string.Join(" ", data12)) / 1000;
                    sw12.WriteLine(datar12);
                    textBox9.Text = datar12.ToString();
                    Array.Clear(data12, 0, data12.Length);
                    Array.Clear(temp12, 0, temp12.Length);
                    //data12 = null;
                }
            }
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(DELAYS);
            ////13 Register
            ushort startAddress13 = 2114;
            byte[] temp13 = null;
            temp13 = modbusMaster.ReadHoldingRegisters(13, string.Format("{0}", startAddress13), 2);
            if (temp13 != null && temp13.Length > 0)
            {
                float[] data13 = IndustrialNetwork.Modbus.DataType.Real.ToArray(temp13);
                //
                //Meter 13 File Write
                using (StreamWriter sw13 = new StreamWriter("MPPGCL_SGTPS_MTR13.txt", true))
                {
                    float datar13 = float.Parse(string.Join(" ", data13)) / 1000;
                    sw13.WriteLine(datar13);
                    textBox20.Text = datar13.ToString();
                    Array.Clear(data13, 0, data13.Length);
                    Array.Clear(temp13, 0, temp13.Length);
                    //data13 = null;
                }
            }
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(DELAYS);
            ////14 Register
            ushort startAddress14 = 2114;
            byte[] temp14 = null;
            temp14 = modbusMaster.ReadHoldingRegisters(14, string.Format("{0}", startAddress14), 2);
            if (temp14 != null && temp14.Length > 0)
            {
                float[] data14 = IndustrialNetwork.Modbus.DataType.Real.ToArray(temp14);
                //
                //Meter 14 File Write
                using (StreamWriter sw14 = new StreamWriter("MPPGCL_SGTPS_MTR14.txt", true))
                {
                    float datar14 = float.Parse(string.Join(" ", data14)) / 1000;
                    sw14.WriteLine(datar14);
                    textBox19.Text = datar14.ToString();
                    Array.Clear(data14, 0, data14.Length);
                    Array.Clear(temp14, 0, temp14.Length);
                    //data14 = null;
                }
            }
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(DELAYS);
            ////15 Register
            ushort startAddress15 = 2114;
            byte[] temp15 = null;
            temp15 = modbusMaster.ReadHoldingRegisters(15, string.Format("{0}", startAddress15), 2);
            if (temp15 != null && temp15.Length > 0)
            {
                float[] data15 = IndustrialNetwork.Modbus.DataType.Real.ToArray(temp15);
                //
                //Meter 15 File Write
                using (StreamWriter sw15 = new StreamWriter("MPPGCL_SGTPS_MTR15.txt", true))
                {
                    float datar15 = float.Parse(string.Join(" ", data15)) / 1000;
                    sw15.WriteLine(datar15);
                    textBox18.Text = datar15.ToString();
                    Array.Clear(data15, 0, data15.Length);
                    Array.Clear(temp15, 0, temp15.Length);
                    //data15 = null;
                }
            }
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(DELAYS);
            ////16 Register
            ushort startAddress16 = 2114;
            byte[] temp16 = null;
            temp16 = modbusMaster.ReadHoldingRegisters(16, string.Format("{0}", startAddress16), 2);
            if (temp16 != null && temp16.Length > 0)
            {
                float[] data16 = IndustrialNetwork.Modbus.DataType.Real.ToArray(temp16);
                //
                //Meter 16 File Write
                using (StreamWriter sw16 = new StreamWriter("MPPGCL_SGTPS_MTR16.txt", true))
                {
                    float datar16 = float.Parse(string.Join(" ", data16)) / 1000;
                    sw16.WriteLine(datar16);
                    textBox17.Text = datar16.ToString();
                    Array.Clear(data16, 0, data16.Length);
                    Array.Clear(temp16, 0, temp16.Length);
                    //data16 = null;
                }
            }
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(DELAYS);
            ////17 Register
            ushort startAddress17 = 2114;
            byte[] temp17 = null;
            temp17 = modbusMaster.ReadHoldingRegisters(17, string.Format("{0}", startAddress17), 2);
            if (temp17 != null && temp17.Length > 0)
            {
                float[] data17 = IndustrialNetwork.Modbus.DataType.Real.ToArray(temp17);
                //
                //Meter 17 File Write
                using (StreamWriter sw17 = new StreamWriter("MPPGCL_SGTPS_MTR17.txt", true))
                {
                    float datar17 = float.Parse(string.Join(" ", data17)) / 1000;
                    sw17.WriteLine(datar17);
                    textBox16.Text = datar17.ToString();
                    Array.Clear(data17, 0, data17.Length);
                    Array.Clear(temp17, 0, temp17.Length);
                    //data17 = null;
                }
            }
            //dataGridView1.DataSource = result.ToArray();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //MessageBox.Show(this, ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }

    private void mainScreenToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        panelMeter1.Visible = true;
        panelFlash.Visible = false;
    }

    private void aboutToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("This Tool has been created by Charles Felix for Reading Meter at MPPGCL");
    }

    private void timerDate_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox2.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString();
    }



}
```

}

Here is the part in which my meter 5 data is carry forwarded to meter 6 data in case the meter 6 holding register is not read, I want no value to be written in the stream writer file and even in the textbox for 6th meter i want the previous read value for meter 6.

```
////5 Register
            ushort startAddress5 = 2114;
            byte[] temp5 = null;
            temp5 = modbusMaster.ReadHoldingRegisters(5, string.Format("{0}", startAddress5), 2);
            if (temp5 != null && temp5.Length > 0)
            {
                float[] data5 = IndustrialNetwork.Modbus.DataType.Real.ToArray(temp5);
                //
                //Meter 5 File Write
                using (StreamWriter sw5 = new StreamWriter("MPPGCL_SGTPS_MTR5.txt", true))
                {
                    float datar5 = float.Parse(string.Join(" ", data5)) / 1000;
                    sw5.WriteLine(datar5);
                    textBox8.Text = datar5.ToString();
                    Array.Clear(data5, 0, data5.Length);
                    Array.Clear(temp5, 0, temp5.Length);
                    //data5 = null;
                }
            }
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(DELAYS);
            ////6 Register
            ushort startAddress6 = 2114;
            byte[] temp6 = null;
            temp6 = modbusMaster.ReadHoldingRegisters(6, string.Format("{0}", startAddress6), 2);
            if (temp6 != null && temp6.Length > 0)
            {
                float[] data6 = IndustrialNetwork.Modbus.DataType.Real.ToArray(temp6);
                //
                //Meter 6 File Write
                using (StreamWriter sw6 = new StreamWriter("MPPGCL_SGTPS_MTR6.txt", true))
                {
                    float datar6 = float.Parse(string.Join(" ", data6)) / 1000;
                    sw6.WriteLine(datar6);
                    textBox7.Text = datar6.ToString();
                    Array.Clear(data6, 0, data6.Length);
                    Array.Clear(temp6, 0, temp6.Length);
                    //data6 = null;
                }
            }
```